# Pip package: expose class members type hints from dependency

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I wrote a python module:

`b.py`

```py
class B:
   pass
```

`a.py`

```py
from b import B

class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.member: B = B()
```

`__init__.py`

```
from ab_package.a import A
from ab_package.b import B
```

I package and install it with pip using a minimalist `setup.py` file:

```py
setup(
    name='ab_package',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='My AB package',
    url='https://github.com/somewhere',
    author='Me',
    author_email='me@somedomain.com',
    license='Private',
    packages=['ab'],
    install_requires=['numpy>=1.19.5',
                      'pandas>=1.3.3',
                      'pylint==2.11.1',
                      'pyparsing~=2.4.7',
                      'requests~=2.26.0',
                      'wget~=3.2',
                      ],

    classifiers=[

    ],
)
```

Then **in another project**, I use it:

```py
from ab_package import A, B

a = A()
myvar = a.member
```

Problem is that in PyCharm, `myvar` is inferred as `Any`.

I can fix it explicitly type-hinting `myvar` but that's not concise enough (especially when my types are much longer than `B`).

How can I make the inference work as expected ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, this sentence *"in PyCharm, b is inferred as Any."* How is it inferred? Besides you used the same letter `b` three or four times but your last `a.b` hasn't been defined anywhere. Yes when you declare a variable you are supposed to hint its type, if the types are too long use an alias.

Comment: Do you intend for `member` in `A.__init__` to be named `self.b`? That would make the question make sense, but I think it would also fix the type hinting issue.

Comment: So sorry, of course there were mistakes, I just fixed them.

Comment: @bad_coder you missed the point. Given I'm speaking about PyCharm it's obvious the question is about static type inferrence, and hinting types for each variable is definitely not an universal standard - even if it may be yours.

Of course a related question could be "how does PyCharm perform static type inferrence", but if I rather ask the one above it's because I think it's related to package declaration and imports, and not PyCharm.

Comment: The import of `b` in `a.py` won't work if the two modules are in a package. You need `from .b import B` (with a dot, signifying a relative import).

Comment: The `__init__.py` file has the same relative import issue as `a.py`. I'd generalize the issues you're having as "type hinting doesn't work right when code has other bugs".

Comment: You pointed out the right issue @Blckknght. The fact that my code was working perfectly when ran directly mislead me. I wonder why it does by the way as you suggest it shouldn't, right? I fixed my question because the imports were not relative in the `__init__.py` file in my package project. Now I definitely now about the right way to package-proofly declare imports, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In the example code you show, the inference that `b` has type `Any` is a symptom of a more severe issue, that you'll get an `AttributeError` when trying to lookup `a.b` in the assignment statement. The type checker `mypy` correctly identifies that as the error, [as you can see here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=791e3d1c40a3d3452a0f1976709a8b5e). I'm not sure about how PyCharm's built in type checking might differ here, though I'd expect it to identify the error too.

If you changed your code to make the `B` instance you create in `A.__init__` an attribute, the code would work and the type can be inferred, [at least by mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=8ceed1dba4fa20db73b0be0117ce8564):

```
class B:
   pass

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b: B = B()   # change member to self.b here

a = A()
b = a.b

reveal_type(b) # type checker reports __main__.B for me, should be ab_package.b.B for you
```

Comment: So sorry there were mistakes in my samples, they're fixed now.
Now if you don't structure your code in a package and import it in another project you'll never see my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Blckknght [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70102460/pip-package-expose-class-members-type-hints-from-dependency#comment123922989_70102460), the problem comes from relative imports between Python files when in a package.

If I just add a dot to the import of `b` making it `from .b import B` in `a.py`, then `a.member` has the right inferred type (as well as `myvar`).

`a.py`

```py
from .b import B

class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.member: B = B()
```